# How can I run an export command and then print the value of an env var via python script?

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I am trying to run an export command via a python script and then print the value of the env variable.

```
import subprocess 
import os 
from pathlib import Path 
import sys 

    
data_path_command_str = "export XYZ=\"/home/\"" 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_str = subprocess.getoutput(data_path_command_str)
    print(output_str)
    home_dir = os.environ['XYZ']
    print(f'{home_dir}')
## END of if
```

However, my script is failing.

**Output:**

```
user_name@server_name:~/server_name_src/4f8e3f8/server_name/bin$ python3 export_test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    home_dir = os.environ['XYZ']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'XYZ'
user_name@server_name:~/server_name_src/4f8e3f8/server_name/bin$
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Exporting a variable makes it available to child processes that are spawned after exporting. It doesn't get inherited by the parent process.

Comment: If you want to update the python process's environment, just assign to `os.environ['XYZ']`